# Animation back to it's starting point

Tags: javascript, html, animation

I've made a small program to animate an image back and forth. Now the first jobbra button works well the image is animating picel by pixel to the right, but my back button balra doesn't work, the image doesn't move back to it's starting point. Is anyone has any idea why, please help. Thank you

```js
var jobbAnim = 1;
var speed = 1;
var balAnim = 400;



function jobbra() {



    if (jobbAnim < 400) {
        jobbAnim = jobbAnim + speed;
    }


    document.getElementById("ilonakep").style.marginLeft = jobbAnim + "px";
    window.requestAnimationFrame(jobbra);

}


function balra() {
    if (balAnim >= 400) {

        balAnim = balAnim - speed;
    }
    document.getElementById("ilonakep").style.marginRight = balAnim + "px";
    window.requestAnimationFrame(balra);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="ilonakep">
        <img src="/img/ilona.jpg" alt="ilona">
    </div>
</div>
<p id="gombok">
    <button onclick="balra()">Balra</button>
    <button onclick="jobbra()">Jobbra</button>
</p>
```

Comment: Is using CSS animations an option for you or are you trying to do it with JS?

Comment: jobbra button function works with JS, i just can't make the img back to it's starting point. Function balra doesn't work.

Comment: Right, I was just asking if you could use CSS animations on your project, as it would be a more elegant solution.

Comment: Nope, honestly I don't know any CSS animation method.I want to make a small game in the end like ping pong so I think JS is a better solution for that.

Comment: "balAnim >= 400" AND balAnim = 400; then balAnim = balAnim - speed;  See the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `cancelAnimationFrame` to make sure you only have one animation playing at a time, otherwise a new animation will be started every time you click one of the buttons. I also, suggest you animate the element's position (or better yet, use `transform: translate();`) rather than the margin. It isn't as ideal as using CSS transitions, but it makes it more intuitive.

```js
var left = 0;
var speed = 1;
var anim;

function jobbra() {
    if (anim) {
        window.cancelAnimationFrame(anim);
    }


    if (left < 400) {
        left = left + speed;
    }

    document.getElementById("ilonakep").style.left = left + "px";
    anim = window.requestAnimationFrame(jobbra);
}


function balra() {
    if (anim) {
        window.cancelAnimationFrame(anim);
    }

    if (left > 0) {
        left = left - speed;
    }

    document.getElementById("ilonakep").style.left = left + "px";
    anim = window.requestAnimationFrame(balra);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="ilonakep" style="position: relative; display: inline;">
        <img src="/img/ilona.jpg" alt="ilona">
    </div>
</div>
<p id="gombok">
    <button onclick="balra()">Balra</button>
    <button onclick="jobbra()">Jobbra</button>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var jobbAnim = 1;
var speed = 1;
var balAnim = 400;



function jobbra() {



    if (jobbAnim < 400) {
        jobbAnim = jobbAnim + speed;
    }


    document.getElementById("ilonakep").style.marginLeft = jobbAnim + "px";
    window.requestAnimationFrame(jobbra);

}


function balra() {
    if (balAnim > 399) {

        balAnim = balAnim - speed;
    }
    document.getElementById("ilonakep").style.marginLeft = balAnim + "px"; //This will reset the element to the left
    document.getElementById("ilonakep").style.marginRight -= balAnim + "px"; //This will move it to the left
    window.requestAnimationFrame(balra);
}
<div id="container">
    <div id="ilonakep">
        <img src="/img/ilona.jpg" alt="ilona">
    </div>
</div>
<p id="gombok">
    <button onclick="balra()">Balra</button>
    <button onclick="jobbra()">Jobbra</button>
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you. Now the img animating for the first time but then it is just jumping form the right corner to the left not animating.

Comment: Did you comment out the first line that resets the element to the left?  It should work if you comment that out.

Answer (score 1):

Using pure CSS animations, you can easily modify how it looks as well. Check out more here - https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

```js
function addLeft() {
    document.getElementById("container").classList.add("slideLeft");
}
function addRight() {
    document.getElementById("container").classList.add("slideRight");
}
```

```css
.slideRight {
    animation-name: slideRight;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes slideRight {
    from {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    to {
        margin-left: 50%;
    }
}

.slideLeft {
    animation-name: slideLeft;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes slideLeft {
    from {
        margin-left: 50%;
    }
    to {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="ilonakep">
        <img src="/img/ilona.jpg" alt="ilona">
    </div>
</div>
<p id="gombok">
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('container').classList.add('slideLeft')">Balra</button>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('container').classList.add('slideRight')">Jobbra</button>
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you but later I want to make a little game from this it is just the first step.

Comment: Ah ok, if you're attempting to make a game I'd recommend looking into the HTML canvas, it's made for drawing and such that you would see in any browser game.

Comment: Thank you! I'll consider it.